# Should I send follow-up email one week after post-doc interview if interviewer said they will make decision in "week or two"?

Tags: postdocs, interview

I had an interview with an UK Institute for my postdoc application last week. At the end of the interview, the PI told me that they will make the decision in a week or two. However, I googled online and I found articles which state that UK Institutes usually make their decisions in two or three days. If you don't hear anything beyond a couple of days, it basically means you are rejected.

I am nervous now. I understand the PI said they will make the decision in a week or two and until today, a week's only past. However, would it hurt my application if I send an email to follow up the decision process? For example, could I send an email to the secretary to ask about the decision process?

Comment: Don't believe everything you read online.  Take into account that the people involved in the decision have a lot of other duties that may make it difficult to schedule a discussion of the candidates. // Waiting is hard.  You need to plan a strategy for the waiting.  Some people find it helpful to do some spring cleaning.  Some find it helpful to dive into a new project, or restart something that was on a back shelf.  Regardless, make sure whatever you choose is fun and helps you get your mind off your waiting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Do not do that. You will receive an e-mail one way or another when the PI makes the decision.

Comment: understood... just want to know the decision... If it indeed a rejection, I may start to apply for other industry jobs...

Comment: 1-2 weeks is virtually nothing. Usually could take 1-2 months or more. Be patient. You will get answer soon one way or another.

Comment: @JumpJump what prevent you from starting to apply elsewhere?